# Can't install Google Chrome on amd64 Wheezy

Tags: debian

```
uname -a
Linux owner 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.82-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I recently installed the amd64 version of Debian Wheezy on my amd64 machine.

Since it's 64 bit, I tried to install Google Chrome because they still support 64 bit Wheezy.

I used GDebi to install it and got the following message:

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libstdc++6(>=4.8.0)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If Chrome requires `libstdc++6` version 4.8.0 or later, that indicates that Google no longer supports 64-bit Wheezy (which only has version 4.7.2).

You should [upgrade](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/releasenotes) to [Debian 8 (Jessie)](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/). That will give you newer versions of all the distribution's software, support for much longer, and you'll be able to install Chrome.

Comment: I installed 64 bit Jessie and installed both Chromium and Chrome. Only problem is that both browsers crash frequently, locking up the screen and requiring a hard reboot
When I click on the browser menu, the menu window pops up and I can read it okay. As soon as I move my pointer over that window it turns black and the font turns large and pixelated. After several attempts, the browser crashes. Same thing with the bookmarks.
Firefox/Iceweasel is the only browser I can depend on at this point.
uname -a
Linux owner 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: That's a separate question really... You might want to try a newer kernel, see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307211/86440) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install the newest version of `libstdc++6` from here: https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libstdc++6/download

Or install chromium instead:

`sudo apt-get install chromium`

Comment: My reason for installing Chrome was because Chromium doesn't work on 64 bit Wheezy per my post at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320515/chromium-on-debian-wheezy-aw-snap-error/322628